# Is there any way to find out if a particular heading is present in a HTML document using dataweave 2.0 or in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a document in which I have to check if the document has a heading called "Name". How can I check this using dataweave?

Example of document:

```
<h2 id="name">Name</h2>
<p>This Anypoint Template should serve as a foundation for setting an online sync of accounts from a Salesforce instance to many destination systems, using the Publish-subscribe pattern. Every time there is a new account or a change in an already existing one, the integration will poll for changes in the Salesforce source Org, publish the changes to a JMS topic and each subscriber will be responsible for updating the accounts in the target systems.</p>
```

Comment: Is any of the solutions shared useful? Please accept/upvote useful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`xpath-extract`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/1.3/xml-xpath) from [`xml-module`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/1.3/) in Mule 4. You can use it to evaluate any XPath against your payload. For example the below XPath will work for you. 
`//*[matches(name(), '^h[1-6]$') and (text() = 'Name')]`

It will match all tags with name that matches regex `^h[1-6]$`, so `h1` to `h6` and has the value ( `text()` ) as `Name`. If you only want to look for `h2` you can update regex part accordingly

```xml
<xml-module:xpath-extract
    doc:name="Xpath extract"
    doc:id="4b04a662-98cb-4dac-b4b5-18f8a9c6604e"
    xpath="//*[matches(name(), '^h[1-6]$') and (text() = 'Name')]">
</xml-module:xpath-extract>
```

The module will return an array of string containing the results of the xpath. You can check if the output of this `isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave doesn't support HTML as a format however it does support XML. If the HTML input has a root tag you can parse as XML and use a recursive function to find if it has a key name and value matching.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import every from dw::core::Arrays
import someEntry from dw::core::Objects
fun findString(x, keyName, s)= x  match {
    case o is Object -> o mapObject (($$): if ($$ as String == keyName and $ == s) true else  findString($, keyName, s) ) someEntry  (value, key) -> value == true
    case s1 is String -> s1
    case is Number -> false
    case is Boolean -> false
    case a is Array -> !((a map findString($, s)) every ($ == false)) // should not happen in XML
    case is Null -> false
    else -> false
  } 
---
findString(payload, "h2", "Name")
```

Input:

```xml
<html>    
  <body>
    <h2 id="name">Name</h2>
    <p>This Anypoint Template should serve as a foundation for setting an online sync of accounts from a Salesforce instance to many destination systems, using the Publish-subscribe pattern. Every time there is a new account or a change in an already existing one, the integration will poll for changes in the Salesforce source Org, publish the changes to a JMS topic and each subscriber will be responsible for updating the accounts in the target systems.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output: `true`